# python html.unescape() doesn't work in concole

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, web-scraping

I need to convert html entites like '&#8217' into Unicode strings. I've read html.unescape function can do it, so I gave it a try.

```
print(html.unescape('&#8217'))
```

This line, if typed in IDLE (Python Shell), works correctly - quotation appears just as it should. But when a create a `.py` file with that line of code and try to compile it, the error happens - `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 0: character maps to <undifined>`.

So why it fails in concole and works in IDLE? And what should I do? I need html entities to be converted as part of a parser I'm writing.

Comment: `html.unescape()` works **fine**. It is **printing** that is the problem, because your console can't handle *that specific character*.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters  Any way to make console aware of this character? If console can't handle it, I can't be sure the later use of that string (which will be put into a database) will not fail..

Comment: For future reference: try *narrowing down the problem*; `result = html.unescape('&#8217')`, then `print(result)` on separate lines would have pointed you to `print()`, not to `html.unescape()`.

Comment: I've duplicated you to the canonical question on Python 3 and printing to the Windows console. Not using the Windows console is one way to avoid this issue.